# How can i float my image to the right side of many paragraphs?

Tags: html, css

What i am trying to do is to make the paragraph texts float left and wrap around the image with a distinct margin and padding and justified and make the image float right to the paragraph text.The image should be at the right-top side of the container and the paragraph should wrap around the image.I have already placed the images and paragraph inside the container div of the bootstrap. How can i achieve this design?

Here is the html code:

```css
#about-us {
  padding: 4em 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#about-us p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  text-align: justify;
  float: left;
}

#about-us img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-us">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Huatai Securities Co.,Ltd. is a leading integrated securities group in China, with a substantial customer base, a leading e-Platform and a highly collaborative full-service business model.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities was established in May 1991.On February 26, 2010, we were listed at Shanghai Stock Exchange with the stock code of 601688. On June 1, 2015, our H Shares have been listed on The Stock Exchange of Hong Kong Limited with the stock code
      of 6886. Over our more than two decades of operating history, we achieved rapid growth by successfully capitalizing on the transformation and innovation opportunities of China's capital market and securities industry. Our major financial indicators
      and business indicators are among the forefront of the domestic securities industry.</p>
    <p>Currently, Huatai Securities has controlling interests in 3 subsidiaries including Huatai United Securities Co., Ltd., Huatai Futures Co.,Ltd., and Jiangsu Equity Exchange Co., Ltd. We have 4 wholly owned subsidiaries including Huatai Financial Holdings(Hong
      Kong) Limited, Huatai Zijin Investment Co., Ltd., Huatai Innovation Investment Co., Ltd., and Huatai Securities (Shanghai) Asset Management Co., Ltd. We also have minority interests in China Southern Asset Management Co., Ltd., Huatai-PineBridge
      Fund Management Co., Ltd., Bank of Jiangsu Co., Ltd., GP Capital Co., Ltd., and E-Capital Transfer Co., Ltd.</p>
    <p>During recent years, Huatai Securities has focused on providing customers with the full life-cycle integrated financial services. We have built a full-service business model which is led by investment banking, underpinned by brokerage and wealth management
      and supported by asset management as well as investment and trading.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities has the largest securities brokerage business in China and a leading e-Platform in the industry. We ranked No.1 in terms of brokerage trading volume of stocks and funds in China's securities industry in 2014.As of the end of 2014,
      the number of our securities brokerage accounts ranked No.1 among all China's securities firms; and the balance of our margin loans and securities lent ranked No.2 and the market value of our client entrusted securities ranked No.3 in China's securities
      industry. Our mobile wealth management terminal, “ZhangLe Fortune Path”, was rated No.1 by Sina.com in its review of mobile securities apps in 2014.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities has a leading comprehensive investment banking franchise and the top M&A advisory business in the industry. In terms of the number of CSRC-approved M&A advised by us, we have been ranked No.1 in the industry for the three consecutive
      years since 2012. In 2014, our equity and debt underwriting businesses also ranked among the top ten securities firms in China, in terms of both value and number of transactions underwritten.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities also has one of the largest comprehensive asset management businesses in China's securities industry, with leading product innovation capability. The AUM of our collective asset management schemes as of the end of 2014 and the net
      revenue from our asset management business in 2014 ranked No.2 and No.3, respectively, in China's securities industry.</p>
    <p>From now on, we plan to leverage our competitive advantages in the securities business to expand our full-service operations, and aim to become a leading integrated financial group which has a profound impact in Asia-Pacific Market with strong local
      advantages and a global vision.</p>
    <img src="images/about-us.png" alt="">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the float property of #about-us p and then move image tag to the top of container div and it will work.

```css
#about-us {
  padding: 4em 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
#about-us p {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  text-align: justify;
}
#about-us img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-us">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://app.sellerseo.com/uploads/print_logo.png" alt="" />
    <p>
              Huatai Securities Co.,Ltd. is a leading integrated securities group in
              China, with a substantial customer base, a leading e-Platform and a
              highly collaborative full-service business model.
    </p>
    <p>
              Huatai Securities was established in May 1991.On February 26, 2010, we
              were listed at Shanghai Stock Exchange with the stock code of 601688.
              On June 1, 2015, our H Shares have been listed on The Stock Exchange
              of Hong Kong Limited with the stock code of 6886. Over our more than
              two decades of operating history, we achieved rapid growth by
              successfully capitalizing on the transformation and innovation
              opportunities of China's capital market and securities industry. Our
              major financial indicators and business indicators are among the
              forefront of the domestic securities industry.
    </p>
    <p>
              Currently, Huatai Securities has controlling interests in 3
              subsidiaries including Huatai United Securities Co., Ltd., Huatai
              Futures Co.,Ltd., and Jiangsu Equity Exchange Co., Ltd. We have 4
              wholly owned subsidiaries including Huatai Financial Holdings(Hong
              Kong) Limited, Huatai Zijin Investment Co., Ltd., Huatai Innovation
              Investment Co., Ltd., and Huatai Securities (Shanghai) Asset
              Management Co., Ltd. We also have minority interests in China Southern
              Asset Management Co., Ltd., Huatai-PineBridge Fund Management Co.,
              Ltd., Bank of Jiangsu Co., Ltd., GP Capital Co., Ltd., and E-Capital
              Transfer Co., Ltd.
    </p>
    <p>
              During recent years, Huatai Securities has focused on providing
              customers with the full life-cycle integrated financial services. We
              have built a full-service business model which is led by investment
              banking, underpinned by brokerage and wealth management and supported
              by asset management as well as investment and trading.
    </p>
    <p>
              Huatai Securities has the largest securities brokerage business in
              China and a leading e-Platform in the industry. We ranked No.1 in
              terms of brokerage trading volume of stocks and funds in China's
              securities industry in 2014.As of the end of 2014, the number of our
              securities brokerage accounts ranked No.1 among all China's securities
              firms; and the balance of our margin loans and securities lent ranked
              No.2 and the market value of our client entrusted securities ranked
              No.3 in China's securities industry. Our mobile wealth management
              terminal, “ZhangLe Fortune Path”, was rated No.1 by Sina.com in its
              review of mobile securities apps in 2014.
    </p>
    <p>
              Huatai Securities has a leading comprehensive investment banking
              franchise and the top M&A advisory business in the industry. In terms
              of the number of CSRC-approved M&A advised by us, we have been ranked
              No.1 in the industry for the three consecutive years since 2012. In
              2014, our equity and debt underwriting businesses also ranked among
              the top ten securities firms in China, in terms of both value and
              number of transactions underwritten.
    </p>
    <p>
              Huatai Securities also has one of the largest comprehensive asset
              management businesses in China's securities industry, with leading
              product innovation capability. The AUM of our collective asset
              management schemes as of the end of 2014 and the net revenue from our
              asset management business in 2014 ranked No.2 and No.3, respectively,
              in China's securities industry.
    </p>
    <p>
              From now on, we plan to leverage our competitive advantages in the
              securities business to expand our full-service operations, and aim to
              become a leading integrated financial group which has a profound
              impact in Asia-Pacific Market with strong local advantages and a
              global vision.
    </p>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works out,Tank you so much but a slight problem is that the image is close to the text if i dont give any margin and if i give margin right to the image it pushes away the text and not itself.The paragraph which are under the image should also be aligned with the image end point.

Comment: Yes. In case, you could add `margin` or `padding` property to image tag.

Comment: Yes. it will wrap all p tag and image tag. So we need it.

Comment: sorry,wrong question why do we have to place the image at the top of the paragraph and after giving float why the paragraph just slides in where there was image before?

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the float left property of the paragraph. And Place the image at the top of paragraphs..

```
#about-us p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  text-align: justify;
}

#about-us img {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: This works out,Tank you so much but a slight problem is that the image is close to the text if i dont give any margin and if i give margin right to the image it pushes away the text and not itself.The paragraph which are under the image should also be aligned with the image end point.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to make the picture at **top** right of you container you need to move the <img> directly under that container.

```css
img {
  float: right;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-us">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""><!-- first child of .container-->
    <p>Huatai Securities Co.,Ltd. is a leading integrated securities group in China, with a substantial customer base, a leading e-Platform and a highly collaborative full-service business model.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities was established in May 1991.On February 26, 2010, we were listed at Shanghai Stock Exchange with the stock code of 601688. On June 1, 2015, our H Shares have been listed on The Stock Exchange of Hong Kong Limited with the stock code
      of 6886. Over our more than two decades of operating history, we achieved rapid growth by successfully capitalizing on the transformation and innovation opportunities of China's capital market and securities industry. Our major financial indicators
      and business indicators are among the forefront of the domestic securities industry.</p>
    <p>Currently, Huatai Securities has controlling interests in 3 subsidiaries including Huatai United Securities Co., Ltd., Huatai Futures Co.,Ltd., and Jiangsu Equity Exchange Co., Ltd. We have 4 wholly owned subsidiaries including Huatai Financial Holdings(Hong
      Kong) Limited, Huatai Zijin Investment Co., Ltd., Huatai Innovation Investment Co., Ltd., and Huatai Securities (Shanghai) Asset Management Co., Ltd. We also have minority interests in China Southern Asset Management Co., Ltd., Huatai-PineBridge
      Fund Management Co., Ltd., Bank of Jiangsu Co., Ltd., GP Capital Co., Ltd., and E-Capital Transfer Co., Ltd.</p>
    <p>During recent years, Huatai Securities has focused on providing customers with the full life-cycle integrated financial services. We have built a full-service business model which is led by investment banking, underpinned by brokerage and wealth management
      and supported by asset management as well as investment and trading.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities has the largest securities brokerage business in China and a leading e-Platform in the industry. We ranked No.1 in terms of brokerage trading volume of stocks and funds in China's securities industry in 2014.As of the end of 2014,
      the number of our securities brokerage accounts ranked No.1 among all China's securities firms; and the balance of our margin loans and securities lent ranked No.2 and the market value of our client entrusted securities ranked No.3 in China's securities
      industry. Our mobile wealth management terminal, “ZhangLe Fortune Path”, was rated No.1 by Sina.com in its review of mobile securities apps in 2014.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities has a leading comprehensive investment banking franchise and the top M&A advisory business in the industry. In terms of the number of CSRC-approved M&A advised by us, we have been ranked No.1 in the industry for the three consecutive
      years since 2012. In 2014, our equity and debt underwriting businesses also ranked among the top ten securities firms in China, in terms of both value and number of transactions underwritten.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities also has one of the largest comprehensive asset management businesses in China's securities industry, with leading product innovation capability. The AUM of our collective asset management schemes as of the end of 2014 and the net
      revenue from our asset management business in 2014 ranked No.2 and No.3, respectively, in China's securities industry.</p>
    <p>From now on, we plan to leverage our competitive advantages in the securities business to expand our full-service operations, and aim to become a leading integrated financial group which has a profound impact in Asia-Pacific Market with strong local
      advantages and a global vision.</p>
    
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works out,Tank you so much but a slight problem is that the image is close to the text if i dont give any margin and if i give margin right to the image it pushes away the text and not itself.The paragraph which are under should also be aligned with the image end point.

Comment: If you need those paragraph right-aligned with this image how about give the margin-right to parentNode *div.container*.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, simply if you use bootstrap , then you should wrap them in div with class row , see here :

```
<section id="about-us">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <p>Huatai Securities Co.,Ltd. is a leading integrated securities group in China, with a substantial customer base, a leading e-Platform and a highly collaborative full-service business model.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
         <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This will helps you to arrange them like you want. 
If you want to use floats , then you should wrap all paragraphs in one div element and img in another div element , something like this :

HTMLCode  :

```
<section id="about-us">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="paragraphs">

    <p>From now on, we plan to leverage our competitive advantages in the securities business to expand our full-service operations, and aim to become a leading integrated financial group which has a profound impact in Asia-Pacific Market with strong local
      advantages and a global vision.</p>
    </div>
   <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS code :

```
#about-us .container{
  padding: 4em 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#about-us .paragraphs{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  text-align: justify;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#about-us .img-container {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Of course in the second example you write your own css . You should gives to the div's elements and width property .

Another way is to use straight flexbox , like they do it in bootstrap 4

Example :

```
#about-us .container{
  padding: 4em 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
}

#about-us .paragraphs{
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  text-align: justify;
}

#about-us .img-container {
  // set if you want width of div container
}
```

Hope this will helps you to understand where is miss the point :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```css
#about-us {
  padding: 4em 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#about-us p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}

#about-us img {
  margin:0 0 20px 20px;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<section id="about-us">
  <div class="container">
   <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="">
    <p>Huatai Securities Co.,Ltd. is a leading integrated securities group in China, with a substantial customer base, a leading e-Platform and a highly collaborative full-service business model.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities was established in May 1991.On February 26, 2010, we were listed at Shanghai Stock Exchange with the stock code of 601688. On June 1, 2015, our H Shares have been listed on The Stock Exchange of Hong Kong Limited with the stock code
      of 6886. Over our more than two decades of operating history, we achieved rapid growth by successfully capitalizing on the transformation and innovation opportunities of China's capital market and securities industry. Our major financial indicators
      and business indicators are among the forefront of the domestic securities industry.</p>
        

    <p>Currently, Huatai Securities has controlling interests in 3 subsidiaries including Huatai United Securities Co., Ltd., Huatai Futures Co.,Ltd., and Jiangsu Equity Exchange Co., Ltd. We have 4 wholly owned subsidiaries including Huatai Financial Holdings(Hong
      Kong) Limited, Huatai Zijin Investment Co., Ltd., Huatai Innovation Investment Co., Ltd., and Huatai Securities (Shanghai) Asset Management Co., Ltd. We also have minority interests in China Southern Asset Management Co., Ltd., Huatai-PineBridge
      Fund Management Co., Ltd., Bank of Jiangsu Co., Ltd., GP Capital Co., Ltd., and E-Capital Transfer Co., Ltd.</p>
    <p>During recent years, Huatai Securities has focused on providing customers with the full life-cycle integrated financial services. We have built a full-service business model which is led by investment banking, underpinned by brokerage and wealth management
      and supported by asset management as well as investment and trading.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities has the largest securities brokerage business in China and a leading e-Platform in the industry. We ranked No.1 in terms of brokerage trading volume of stocks and funds in China's securities industry in 2014.As of the end of 2014,
      the number of our securities brokerage accounts ranked No.1 among all China's securities firms; and the balance of our margin loans and securities lent ranked No.2 and the market value of our client entrusted securities ranked No.3 in China's securities
      industry. Our mobile wealth management terminal, “ZhangLe Fortune Path”, was rated No.1 by Sina.com in its review of mobile securities apps in 2014.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities has a leading comprehensive investment banking franchise and the top M&A advisory business in the industry. In terms of the number of CSRC-approved M&A advised by us, we have been ranked No.1 in the industry for the three consecutive
      years since 2012. In 2014, our equity and debt underwriting businesses also ranked among the top ten securities firms in China, in terms of both value and number of transactions underwritten.</p>
    <p>Huatai Securities also has one of the largest comprehensive asset management businesses in China's securities industry, with leading product innovation capability. The AUM of our collective asset management schemes as of the end of 2014 and the net
      revenue from our asset management business in 2014 ranked No.2 and No.3, respectively, in China's securities industry.</p>
    <p>From now on, we plan to leverage our competitive advantages in the securities business to expand our full-service operations, and aim to become a leading integrated financial group which has a profound impact in Asia-Pacific Market with strong local
      advantages and a global vision.</p>
   
  </div>
</section>
```